# asp.net Disable master page menu

Tags: asp.net

Im working with asp.net and c#.
I have a master page and many aspx pages that use it.

The master page has a menu defined which is inside an unordered list(html).

I want to be able to disable the menu from the master page, from one of the aspx pages(lets call it page1), when the page1 loads.

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu" runat ="server"> 
     <li>
         <a href="#" class="menulink">Mant</a>
             <ul> 
                 <li><a href="Mant.aspx">Table</a></li> 
            </ul> 
     </li> 
</ul>
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Has `unordered list(html)` `runat="server"` and `ID`?

Comment: Can you show `List` html code?

Comment: Are you using javascript on your page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to  disable `list` from master page, then you can use this code in master page's `Load` event.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ContentPlaceHolder1.Page.GetType().Name=="webform1_aspx")
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder1.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", "javascript: document.getElementById('menu').style.visibility = 'hidden';", true);                
        }
    }
```

If you want to use it in content page's load event then use this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", "javascript: document.getElementById('menu').style.visibility = 'hidden';",true);
```

And menu is like this.

```
<ul id="listMenu" runat="server">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @pyram Perhaps consider updating your _question_ with additional requirements? The comments under this answer just degenerate into chat. I realize you can't join chat, but this sort of discussion is not what comments are for.

Comment: @Tim Post : Please guide me how can I help him,  if he can't join me in chat ? I agree with you comments are not for chat.

Comment: @jams Well, go at it if you must, but this will continue to raise system flags if not resolved quickly. You are a 4k+ user so I'll trust that you can guide the OP to open a new question if needed. No need to delete your previous comment. Please, however make _sure_ all of this gets moved into the question and your answer as appropriate :) Then, please flag any comments that are obsolete as obsolete.

Comment: @Tim Post : Thanks for trusting me :)

Comment: @pyram : Please see my updated answer with content page solution.

Comment: it worked. I just had to put true at the end like this:  `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", "javascript: document.getElementById('menu').style.visibility = 'hidden';", true);`....thanks!!

Comment: Sorry It was my typo :). Better you get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access from content page like this :

```
MasterPagename ms = Master as MasterPagename ;
ms.NavigatorMenu.Items[0].disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use content place holders:

Ex Master Page:

Add:

```
<asp:contentplaceholder id="Menu" runat="server">
<!-- Menu here -->
</asp:contentplaceholder>
```

In Content Pages(Page1 in your example) where you `dont want to show` menu add following tag and remove this from all content pages where you want menu to show:

```
<asp:Content ID="menuContent1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Menu" Runat="Server">    
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

To find menu items in content page and disable it on pageload()

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


Menu mainMenu = (Menu)Page.Master.FindControl("NavigationMenu");

  foreach (MenuItem m in mainMenu.Items)
    {
        m.Enabled = false;
}

}
```