# Remove My ASP.NET Application master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How do I remove **My ASP.NET Application** master page?

It appears by default on output screen of **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010**

[image]

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861743/asp-net-disable-master-page-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new Master Page suppose MasterPage.master
2. Open Default.aspx file change **MasterPageFile** property

   From `<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"%>`

   To   `<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" %>`
3. Update **ContentPlaceHolderID** with the ID which is provided in MasterPage.master file.

Answer (score 2):

Change the MasterPageFile of your Default.aspx (or whatever your aspx file is). You can choose to create your own master file or remove the content control from aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TempTest._Default" %>
```